# Combine 2 lists in the same dictionary in Python3

Tags: python

I am trying to write an application in Python3 that will transfer files to a list of IP addresses. I want to be able to chose whether to send the file to one list of IP addresses, the other list, or to both of them at the same time. I have everything working with the exception of combining two lists.

Here is what I am working with:

```
 ip_list = {
 "list1":['a.a.a.a', 'b.b.b.b'],
 "list2":['c.c.c.c', 'd.d.d.d'],
 "both": [itertools.chain("list1", "list2")]}
```

Now when I try to print the list "both" using:

```
for device in ip_list["both"]
     print(device)
```

all I get is <itertools.chain object at 0x0000....>

Is there another method that I should be using to accomplish this?

Comment: Unpack generator: list(gen)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just do `itertools.chain("list1", "list2")`

That's going to give you a list of strings `['l', 'i', 's', 't', '1', 'l', 'i', 's', 't', '2']`

You also don't need to use `chain`

The proper way is to do this:

```py
ip_list = {
    "list1":['a.a.a.a', 'b.b.b.b'],
    "list2":['c.c.c.c', 'd.d.d.d'],
}

ip_list["both"] = ip_list["list1"] + ip_list["list2"]
```

Comment: Note that `itertools.chain` _doesn't_ give you a _list_ (that's what OP is complaining about in the first place) -- it gives you an generator that will contain elements from all the input iterables.

Comment: You could pass that iterator to the "list" class constructor, but just adding them is clearer. This is the way to go if you just want those specific hardcoded names.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your approach:

1. `itertools.chain` returns a *[generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)*, not a *list*. When you do `[itertools.chain(...)]`, it simply creates a list with the generator from `chain` as its first element. It doesn't unpack all the elements of the generator into the list. To do that, you need `list(itertools.chain(...))` or `[*itertools.chain(...)]`
2. `itertools.chain` chains *all the input iterables* to each other. This means that when you do `itertools.chain("list1", "list2")`, the arguments `"list1"` and `"list2"` (which are *strings*) are chained together. Note that these do not refer to the values you previously specified in the dictionary. There is no way to refer to another key in the dictionary while you are defining your dictionary. If you try to print the elements of this `chain` call, you'll see what it contains:

```
for elem in itertools.chain("list1", "list2"):
    print(repr(elem), end="\t")
```

Which prints a bunch of single-character strings:

```
'l' 'i' 's' 't' '1' 'l' 'i' 's' 't' '2'
```

3. Since you're putting the result of the `chain` in a list anyway, you don't eve *need to use `chain`!* You could simply concatenate the two lists using the `+` operator.

So you need to refer to the *actual values* of the `"list1"` and `"list2"` keys of your dict. Remember, these are not accessible through the dictionary until *after the dict is completely defined*. You could either define the values themselves separately like so:

```
# Create the lists, store them in separate variables
list1 = ['a.a.a.a', 'b.b.b.b']
list2 = ['c.c.c.c', 'd.d.d.d']

ip_list = {
    "list1": list1
    "list2": list2
    "both": list1 + list2
}
```

Or, you could do what [007 suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73198141/843953) and create the `"both"` key after you've finished defining the dictionary.

```
ip_list = {
    "list1":['a.a.a.a', 'b.b.b.b'],
    "list2":['c.c.c.c', 'd.d.d.d'],
}

ip_list["both"] = ip_list["list1"] + ip_list["list2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose instead we just iterate over all the values in ip_list.
Those are themselves iterable, and you're just iterating over them, so there's no need to store it anywhere. Just treat them as one continuous source with chain, like so:

```
from itertools import chain

ip_list = {
    "list1":['a.a.a.a', 'b.b.b.b'],
    "list2":['c.c.c.c', 'd.d.d.d'],
}

for addr in chain.from_iterable(ip_list.values()):
    print(addr)
```

> a.a.a.a
> b.b.b.b
> c.c.c.c
> d.d.d.d

However, it's much easier if you just have specific names you want to include:

```
targets = ('list1', 'list2')
for name in targets:
    for addr in ip_list[name]:
        print(addr)
```

Comment: Here, I'm assuming that you want to use the ip_list dynamically, and prefer iterators. If you just have that specific case with a few specific names, this is overkill.